# how to make a click event on a textview of child of a custom listview in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-listview, textview

Basically I'm new to Android and don't know much about it. I'm making a quiz program in which I'm  using custom `ListView` with 5 custom `TextViews`, one for question and other 4 for options. My problem is that I want the `TextView` as clickable as well as the `LisView` as choice mode as single. That is if I click one text all other `TextView`s should become unclickable. My problem is whenever I click on a `TextView` in the child layout, only the outer layout, that is the item of the `ListView` get selected.
here is the screenshot of the my listview

https://picasaweb.google.com/108429569548433380582/Android?authkey=Gv1sRgCJ3kxJz7tLvaTg#5783846428648608706

Comment: Did you extends `ListView` in your Custom View?

Comment: sorry how to do it let me check it and i will be back with results...by the way thanks buddy have a look on my list view its like this 
 https://picasaweb.google.com/108429569548433380582/Android?authkey=Gv1sRgCJ3kxJz7tLvaTg#5783846428648608706

Comment: are you asking about did i extended the adapter ?? sorry i didn't get you please tell me what you  asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

When you select one textview the other three will be unclickable

```
    final TextView texta = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_a);
    final TextView textb = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_b);
    final TextView textc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_c);
    final TextView textd = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_d);
    texta.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            textb.setClickable(false);
            textc.setClickable(false);
            textd.setClickable(false);
        }

    });
    textb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            texta.setClickable(false);
            textc.setClickable(false);
            textd.setClickable(false);
        }

    });
    textc.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            texta.setClickable(false);
            textb.setClickable(false);
            textd.setClickable(false);
        }

    });
    textd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            texta.setClickable(false);
            textb.setClickable(false);
            textc.setClickable(false);
        }

    });
```

Comment: first thanks adam for the help but still my problem persists whenever i click textviews it is not responding i think the row item of list view is still clicked whenever i want to click textviews may b the screenshot will help you more to answer my question                                    https://picasaweb.google.com/108429569548433380582/Android?authkey=Gv1sRgCJ3kxJz7tLvaTg#5783846428648608706            i want to do, as whenever i click a textview it will get selected and it will check the text in selected textview with a preloaded answer. but the row item is getting selected all the time.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two ways:

**1.** Either by directly using onClickListener like this:

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            // Do anything here.

        }
    });
```

OR

**2.** In `XML` file, in declaration of `<TextView />` add one more attribute as:

```
android:onClick="onClickTextView"
```

and in yout activity, add this function:

```
public void onClickTextView(View view) {

         // Do anything here.
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Use following code to get click event on TextView:

```
// Click event for single list row
        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                TextView tv = (TextView) (findViewById(R.id.title));
                if (tv != null) {
                    tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "CLICKED",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "TV not found",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: surely i will try this okay and will report you as early as possible...by the way thnks buddy

Comment: i tried what you suggested but i think the problem is that when i click on text view, the row item of list view is selected not the text view in its child i m sending you a link of the screenshot of my app have a look on that buddy and suggest me some more help  [link](https://picasaweb.google.com/108429569548433380582/Android?authkey=Gv1sRgCJ3kxJz7tLvaTg#5783846428648608706 )

Comment: should i use buttons with custom backgrounds, will it make some differences??? reply me some other methods dude

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please see it. Sorry for late reply.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply shrikant. Pardon me but i changed the whole concept i used radio button. But view holder solves the problem.

Comment: Sorry to bump this, I tried the solution in the Update part, and it is supposed to be `TextView tv = (TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.title);` I edited it in.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you extend BaseAdapter to set the listview content ->

Open a TextView listener and settag of the current holder position , and perform your operation in the onclick method.

Comment: dude can you suggest any example or some sites for this here, as i m new to the android.

Answer (score 0):

It's the default behavior of a ListView. Only one could be clickable: either the list row or the items inside the row.

> Eg: if the row item is a textView(as in your case) the list row will be clickable but if the row item is a button then the the list row will not be clickable. Same is the case if you make TextView as clickable.

For your requirement the better approach would be to use RadioGroup (instead of multiple text view and disabling and enabling them).
You should use a custom layout for you list item with a TextView for question and a RadioGroup for options.

Layout could be something like this :
[image]

Follow these links for reference:
for [listView](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/) 

for [RadioGroup](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-radio-buttons-example/)

I hope this will help

Comment: After looking at the link to the picture I can say that you don't need a TextView, all you need is a rounded buttons as the options. And onClick you can remove the text of the button(wrong options). Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: actually karn that option textview had some animations i think i should use simple buttons so that i can change there background as a custom one,,, well thanks for the reply my friend. i will your option in my if everything goes in vain what i did i will opt your opinion..keep posting if you get any idea

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Shrikant and adam for there help Sorry and i appologize for a very late response.

either use this in adapter class as by Shrikant:

```
textViewa.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Do anything here.
        }
    });

    textViewb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Do anything here.
        }
    });

    //and so on...

    // or better to use ViewHolder holder; for these type of listviews;

    View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            // Do what you want to do.

            // for my i have to call a method in my parent activity. so in    constructor of adapter, I passed the activity and then typecasted it like

            ParentActivity parent = (ParentActivity) activity;
            parent.chosenAnswer(view.getId());

            // then in chosenAnswer(int id) in parentActivity use a switch case for the same logic as in Adam's answer.

            // OR 
            //you can write like this too..

            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.textViewa:
                    break;
                case R.id.textViewb:
                    break;
                case R.id.textViewc:
                    break;
                case R.id.textViewd:
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
```